# How do I avoid repopulating my dropdownlist on postback?

Tags: asp.net

In asp.net I enable the autopostback property in a dropdown list . whenever i select a list item of dropdown menu same list items added in to dropdown list this probles how can i solved?

Comment: It sounds like you are initialising controls on every load instead of only on the first, but that's impossible to tell for certain unless you show your code for it.

Answer (score 1):

Check for the [Page.IsPostBack Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.ispostback(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
private void Page_Load()
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        // load combo box
        ...
    }
}
```